# How to use (IN) Operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to use the `IN` operator in SQL Server? I am using one table with 5 columns. But I want to get selected columns through a stored procedure like

```
 Select * 
 From products 
 Where proprice between @price1 and @price2 
   and categoryid in (@cID)
```

When I execute this stored procedure, it executes successfully. But I pass values to three parameters I cannot get the correct data returned.

Data sample:

```
ProductID ProductName ProductImage           ProductPrice
 20       Nike Shoe   ~/Images/NikeShoe1.jpg 5000
```

Comment: show how your sample data looks like

Comment: In categoryid column we hav multiple Ids when i give a query below                                       sp_range '1000','25000',('1,2') ...I tried this format it cannot get the correct value

Comment: Add sample data of your table and `@cID` variable

Comment: ProductID   ProductName                                        ProductImage           ProductPrice

20          Nike Shoe                                          ~/Images/NikeShoe1.jpg   5000

Comment: Please include `data` in the question detail (not as unformatted comment). It is good practice to include some details of tables and data to get sensible answers. For this question what I suggest you include is an example of what you put into @cID  **in particular is this a comma separated list of values?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

Make sure  you are passing paramters as `'1,2'` not `'(1,2)'`

```
Select * 
from products 
where (proprice between @price1 and @price2) and (CHARINDEX(','+CAST(categoryid as VARCHAR(8000))+ ',', ','+@cID+',')>0)
```

if you are passing parameters as `'(1,2)'`

```
select @cid=REPLACE(@cid,'(','');
select @cid=REPLACE(@cid,')','');

Select * 
from products 
where (proprice between @price1 and @price2) and (CHARINDEX(','+CAST(categoryid AS VARCHAR(8000))+ ',', ','+@cID+',')>0)
```

Comment: Does not make any difference...all are `AND` operators. Problem is in validating `@cID` variable

Comment: sp_range '1000','25000',('1,2') i tried this format

Comment: @VasanthJack, don't pass ids inside (), instead pass it like '1,2' and use the updated answer. It should work.

Comment: @jibin And am using the paramter '@'cID datatype is varchar(max) it s Ryt or wrng

Comment: @VasanthJack, I have updated my answer, do check it and let me know if you still have any issue.

Comment: No sir I have no issue on the query U give...Itz working fine... thank yue So much

Comment: @JibinBalachandran   Itz Working Finee

Comment: @JibinBalachandran , Hi Jibin.May i know which data type is used to getting multiple value from sql

Comment: @JibinBalachandran   R u there

Comment: @VasanthJack Sorry, I didn't get your issue.. What you mean by `multiple value from sql`?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran alter Procedure sp_range_chkbox       
Price int,        
Price1 int,      
chkValue varchar(max)  
as        
begin        
IF  (chkValue > 0)        
begin        
select ProductID,ProductName,ProductImage,ProductPrice from tblProddetails where (ProductPrice between Price and Price1) and (CHARINDEX(','+Categoryid+ ',', ','+chkvalue+',')>0)    
end        
else        
begin        
select ProductID,ProductName,ProductImage,ProductPrice from tblProddetails where ProductPrice between Price and Price1          
end        
end  ........

Comment: This is my store Procedure ...In this am using if condtion .If the condition is true we get muliple id's .but it show me datatype error

Comment: If the condition is true I executed Like this    (sp_range_chkbox '200','500','1,2')   the error is "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int."

Comment: @VasanthJack It's very difficult to read and understand that. Can you pull out a new question with all the details and add the link here?

Comment: @VasanthJack Ok I got it, use `CAST(Categoryid AS VARCHAR(8000))` instead of just `Categoryid` inside the `CHARINDEX()`. I have updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Same Error display Again Jibin.

Comment: What's the datatype of `Categoryid `?

Comment: Category Id is the column name and it is a Identitycolumn and its Datatype is INT

Comment: @VasanthJack Then CAST(CategoryId AS VARCHAR(8000)) should work.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Hi Jibin.Same error throw again.Anyother way to get the clear Output values

Comment: May i know How to use the (IN) Operator inside the categoryID.

Comment: @VasanthJack Can you show the data inside categoryid column and the data you are passing??

Comment: CategoryID  CategoryName

1           Electronics
2           Footwear
3           Accessories
4           Leather

Comment: @JibinBalachandran  
IF (chkValue > 0).How to use Length in If condtion

Comment: @JibinBalachandran R u There?

Comment: @VasanthJack LEN(chkValue) I guess you will get all this in a simple google search.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Hi, I have a doubt in bus seat selection.Shall i post a link here .

Comment: @VasanthJack Ya sure

Comment: @JibinBalachandran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458165/bus-seat-selection-in-asp-net

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Hi

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Can u Help me how to design a Bus seat booking in asp,net

Comment: @JibinBalachandran How to get column names based on column values in sql server

Comment: @JibinBalachandran     http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-implement-datalist-inside-gridview-in-asp-net

Comment: @JibinBalachandran R u there?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611845/how-to-get-the-label-values-which-is-inside-the-gridview-in-static-method

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the values are comma separated. Also read about normalisation

```
Select * from products 
 where proprice between @price1 and @price2 and '%,'+categoryid+',%' like '%,'+@cID+'%,'
```

Comment: I tried this query also it cannot get the proper datas

Comment: Post some sample data and the format of @cID values

Comment: sp_range '1000','25000',('1,2')