# How to get the label values which is inside the Gridview in static method

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a label which is inside the Gridview. I want the label value inside the static method. This is my code:

```
public static string seat(string SeatNum)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        Label lblSeatNum = (Label)page.FindControl("lblSeatNo");
        Label lblfare = (Label)page.FindControl("lblTotfare");
        GridView grd = (GridView)page.FindControl("rptrbus");
        lblSeatNum.Text = SeatNum.ToString();
        Label lblgrdfare = (Label)grd.FindControl("lbFare");
        lblfare.Text = lblgrdfare.Text;


    }
        int dt=0;
    return dt.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Nice. Is everything working fine?

Comment: no,I cant get the values?is my code is Right or Wrong

Comment: @TimSchmelter Its throws an error.Object refernce error will shown

Comment: @TimSchmelter Same error occur man.Any other method?

Comment: Why you comment your own question?

Answer (score 0):

What about the following code:

```
Label lblSeatNum = (Label)page.FindControl("lblSeatNo");
if(lblSeatNum  != null)
     string text = lblSeatNum .Text;
```